# PHP - Trait ou Classe extendida

Tags: php, mvc, modelagem, padrão-dao

Boa tarde pessoal,
Tenho uma trait que **formata dados dos Models** em um **sistema MVC**, o sistema funciona corretamente, entretanto me veio uma duvida em relação a design pattern e performance, no caso, o uso da trait está correto ou deveria considerar extender uma **classe Model** ao invés de utiliza-la como **trait**?

**trait model**:

```
trait Model
{
    function __construct($attributes=array())
    {
        if(sizeof($attributes) > 0){
            foreach ($attributes as $key => $value) {
                $this->$key = $value;
            }
        }
    }

    function __set($name, $value)
    {
        if(in_array($name, self::COLUMN)){
            $this->$name = $value;
        }
    }

    function __get($name)
    {
        if(isset($this->$name)){
            return $this->$name;
        }
    }

    function __unset($name)
    {
        if(isset($this->$name)){
            unset($this->name);
        }
    }
}
```

**modelo usuário**:

```
class User 
{
    const COLUMN = array(

        'iduser',
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'permission',
        'status',
        'date_created'

    );

    use Model;
}
```

Comment: Como é dito no próprio manual do PHP: "Uma Característica destina-se a reduzir algumas limitações da herança única, permitindo que um desenvolvedor reutilize conjuntos de métodos livremente em várias classes independentes que residem em hierarquias de classes diferentes.". Pelo visto este não é o seu caso. Então, não! Não utilize Trait.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para responder suas perguntas precisamos deixar bem claro o que são **Traits**.

> ### O que é um Trait?
>
> Traits são pedaços individuais de código que definem métodos que podem ser utilizados por diferentes classes para proporcionar uma funcionalidade adicional. Esse é um recurso introduzido no PHP 5.4.
>
> Traits são muito parecidos com classes abstratas, com algumas diferenças que lhes permitem ser utilizados por várias classes independentes ao mesmo tempo. Quando penso em Traits, eu imagino um conjunto de ferramentas como chaves de fenda (screwDrivers). Se uma classe quer usá-las, basta pedir.
>
> *Fonte: [IMasters](https://imasters.com.br/back-end/como-fazer-uma-melhor-reutilizacao-de-codigo-php-usando-traits-parte-01)*

É muito interessante pensar no exemplo da caixa de ferramentos, pois a ideia é justamente essa. Falando cruamente, você teria com os Traits, formas para criar um conjunto de funções que podem ser acessadas facilmente pelas classes. Sabe aquelas funções que você constrói e acaba usando em diversas classes, mas ai você declara ela dentro de cada classe e consequentemente acaba tendo uma repetição do código? Seus problemas acabaram, os Traits chegaram pra trazer a reutilização de código pra sua vida.

---

#### Exemplo:

```
trait Validacoes {

    public function validarCPF($cpf) {
        // Aqui vai a lógica de validação e retorna o resultado da mesma
        return true;
    }

    public function validarEmail($email) {
        // Aqui vai a lógica de validação e retorna o resultado da mesma
        return true;
    }

    public function validarCNPJ($cnpj) {
        // Aqui vai a lógica de validação e retorna o resultado da mesma
        return true
    }
}
```

Neste trait por exemplo tenho formas de realizar determinadas validações. Poderia usar ela na minha classe `Usuario` para validar as entradas de dados.

```
class Usuario {
    use Validacoes;

    private $cpf;
    private $email;
    private $cnpj;

    public function salvar($dados) {
        $this->cpf = $this->validarCPF($dados->cpf) ? $dados->cpf : '';
        $this->email = $this->validarEmail($dados->email) ? $dados->email : '';
        $this->cnpj = $this->validarCNPJ($dados->cnpj) ? $dados->cnpj : '';
    }
}
```

Poderia ainda usar outros traits dentro da minha classe, bastando usar `use Validacoes, Utilidades;`, no caso de eu querer convocar outro Trait chamado Utilidades. Vale ressaltar aqui que essa inclusive é uma das vantagens desse recurso. Uma classe estendida tem a herança exclusiva, porém usando traits, você pode usar tantos quanto quiser, possibilitando inclusive resolver conflitos caso traits diferentes tenham uma mesma função.

Diferentemente de quando você simplesmente usa um `include`, chama um arquivo com funções e as usa diretamente dentro das classes, os traits são compatíveis com o POO (Programação Orientada a Objetos), essa é uma grande vantagem também no seu caso, pois estamos falando de um universo MVC.

---

#### Respondendo as perguntas pensando no âmbito MVC:

Ao pensar no universo MVC, poderíamos usar os traits dentro de um model ou controller, dependendo da necessidade. No caso apresentado em específico, o que é melhor ou mais correto, **usar** essas funções que você criou dentro do trait ou **estender** uma classe model? Como já falamos o principal objetivo do trait é reaproveitar código, portanto a resposta a sua pergunta é simples, se o seu código se repetir em diversas classes, sejam elas controller ou model, utilize o trait, vai facilitar a manutenção.

Sobre performance simplesmente não afetará em nada.

---

### Conclusão

Recomenda-se o uso de traits sempre que existir funções que se repitam em duas ou mais classes, viabilizando assim a reutilização de código.

Answer (score 0):

Nesse caso, herdar não seria um problema se `User` é realmente uma especificação do código mais genérico que está na trait. Por isso, você poderia transformar essa trait em uma classe abstrata e herdar dela, pois a relação de herança faz sentido nessas classes.

Também seria mais adequado renomear a classe `Model` para algo mais voltado para a entidade, pois ela contém somente código para setar dados para uma determinada entidade. Ao meu ver o nome é o problema e não o fato de você estar utilizando uma trait.

OBS: É importante lembrar que model é uma camada do MVC que comporta classes referentes as regras de negócio da aplicação, portanto model não é necessariamente uma classe chamada model, mas sim todo um conjunto de classes. Nomear uma classe como model não acrescenta informação ao código.